# SMD IC help - identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

Can you identify what is this SMD IC with 5 pins?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide dimensions?

Comment: That looks like an SOT23-5 package, but unfortunately those markings are quite unrecognizable and therefore there is no good way to identify it. Could you provide information regarding the type of circuit it is used in: i.e, what the circuit board does, full images of the circuit etc. as there might be other distinguishing markings. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Fairchild (now onsemi) NC7ST00M5X](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/NC7ST00-98317.pdf) NAND gate.

[image]

Below is a picture that shows the marking style matches.

[image]

(Source: [aliexpress.ru](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005005296660903.html?sku_id=12000032532178654))

Note: The font seems to have changed on newer parts produced by onsemi. I suspect the one here is an old version when it was still produced by Fairchild. Other former Fairchild parts like the FAN3100 used the same font.